# Android actionbar behaving strangely

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, searchview

I am trying to create a good looking SearchView. I used [this](http://droidmentor.com/searchview-animation-like-whatsapp/) code and integrated it in my DrawerLayout. This is the current XML of my main activity:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main_search"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
```

My app_bar_main_search.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/searchtoolbar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

My main_layout.xml is just a file with a FAB and an empty constraintlayout.

The code above works, but the main layout is underneath the actionbar and the NavigationDrawer icon in the top-left corner stopped working (except if I take the NavigationDrawer out by swiping, then it starts working again for some reason). Removing the RelativeLayout around the actionbars makes the app_bar_main cover the entire screen. Assigning an ID to the app_bar_main makes it entirely empty, just a background color.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the main layout below the actionbar?

EDIT: I got the toolbar working with @FAT's answer, but the navigationdrawer icon still isn't working. This is the relevant code:

```
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

I tried adding the syncState() to the onPostCreate but this did not change anything. The onOptionsItemSelected function also does not get called when I click the icon.

Comment: Won't it work if you put the first RelativeLayout above the first include?

Comment: @cristianorbs Nope, that makes the entire actionbar disappear with the screen being filled with the main_layout.xml

Comment: And what if in your main_layout, you put layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" on the parent view?

Comment: @cristianorbs Yes I also tried that, that did not do anything at all for some reason

Comment: Have you already tried to change the relative layout height to wrap_content instead of match_parent?

Comment: Just tried, also changes nothing.

Comment: `DrawerLayout` should have only one main content `View`. Put everything that is not a drawer inside the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` should have at most two views. Inside the `DrawerLayout`, add one view that contains the `main` content for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the `navigation` drawer.

[See documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

> To use a `DrawerLayout`, position your primary `content` view as the
>   `first` child with width and height of match_parent and no
>   layout_gravity>. Add `drawers` as child views after the main content
>   view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use
>   match_parent for height with a fixed width.

**1.** Keep your `main_layout` inside first direct child `RelativeLayout`.

**2.** Add attribute `android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_main"` to main_layout.

**Update your layout XML as below:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/appbar" 
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main_search"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I assign an ID to the app_bar_main, the content suddenly disappears. It just turns into an empty actionbar.

Comment: I got it working, the issue was that the toolbar inside of app_bar_main already had an ID, so I removed that one and added it to the include. It works now. The NavigationDrawer icon still isn't working though.

Comment: I see. For drawer icon try this>>> DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

Comment: Yes I already have that exact code. I'll update the OP with what I have.

Comment: If my answer seems useful and helps to resolve your problem, then please mark as right answer and vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks dear for accepting my answer. It would be a great help if you can vote it up to reach my reputation 6k. Thanks in advance :)